# Django Auth is not finding User Account in LDAP

Tags: django, authentication, ldap, django-views

Morning,

I´m implementing Django Auth Ldap in my proyect but it is not working. I checked ldap connection (by Django shell) and returns a search, so I guess python-ldap is working. I used the next:

```
import ldap
con = ldap.initialize("ldap://hostname")
con.simple_bind_s( "CN=MyName MySurname, CN=Users, DC=CompanyName, DC=local", "MyPassword" )
con.search_s( 'DC=CompanyName, DC=local', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectclass=person)', ['sn'] )
```

When I try to authenticate an user by web (using Django-Auth-Ldap), authentication always returns None.

```
Settings. (LDAP Configuration).
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://hostname"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=MyName MySurname, CN=Users, DC=CompanyName, DC=local"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "MyPassword"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("CN=Users, DC=CompanyName, DC=local", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: False
}

from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
View.
def Login(request):
 usr = "MyUserName"
 pwd = "MyPassword"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ldap_backend = LDAPBackend()
        user = ldap_backend.authenticate(usr, pwd)
        print user
        print usr, pwd
```

In my view, I´m passing to the ldap authentication my user and password which I used for login in the domain. Is that correct?
I got the value `"CN=MyName MySurname, CN=Users, DC=CompanyName, DC=local"` from a command in Directory Active server, kind of: **dsquery user**

This is the AD Schema:
[image: AD Structure]

What Am I Doing wrong?

Thanks guys.

EDITED: The problem is when I define the search throug uid, if I define it as **AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("CN=Users, DC=CompanyName, DC=local", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(CN=%(user)s)")** is working (and, in the view, I must to pass as **usr = "MyNameMySurname"** instead). How can I Define the search through the username which I used for login it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally... I must to use samAccountName instead of CN. I hope it help you all. Thanks guys.